# Inserting a document into MongoDB wthout _id field seems bugged

Tags: mongodb, go, objectid

I might have found a weird bug..
I do update once in a while my mongodb-driver package as I use for year now I layer I've made a long time ago.

However, today, for some personal reasons, I have refactored my tests and now have e2e full tests suite over my layer. The thing is, while doing my tests, I could reproduce a bug I had in the past, which is when I don't set an ID for my document (_id bson field)

**Situation:**

> For obvious reason, some piece of code are missing but I am quite sure you will be able to guess really easily ;)
>
> The commented out code part is the tests that are creating the weird behavior

- If I create a document (really simple struct) and set the _id field before inserting, it works perfectly.
- If I create a document (really simple struct) and don't set the _id field before inserting, it inserts something that results as "null" while observing the database using Robo3T.

**Code:**

To reproduce that bug, there is my tests and the source code of my layer

***Tests:***

```
type e2eMongoDBSuite struct {
    suite.Suite
    _mongodb mongodb.IMongoDB
}

type e2eTestDocument struct {
    ID         *primitive.ObjectID `json:"_id" bson:"_id"`
    ValueStr   string              `json:"value_str" bson:"value_str"`
    ValueInt32 int32               `json:"value_int32" bson:"value_int32"`
}

const (
    //// ci
    connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017"
    databaseName     = "mongodb-database-e2e-tests"
    collection       = "mongodb-collection-e2e-tests"
    defaultTimeout   = 5 * time.Second
)

func (e2eSuite *e2eMongoDBSuite) SetupSuite() {
    var err error
    if e2eSuite._mongodb, err = mongodb.New(&mongodb.Config{
        ConnectionString: connectionString,
        DatabaseName:     databaseName,
        DefaultTimeout:   defaultTimeout,
    }); err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Errorf("couldn't setup suite: %w", err).Error())
    }
}

func (e2eSuite *e2eMongoDBSuite) TestInsertOneWithID_OK() {
    a := assert.New(e2eSuite.T())

    // given
    docID := e2eSuite._mongodb.GenerateNewObjectID()
    doc := &e2eTestDocument{ID: docID}

    // when
    insertedID, err := e2eSuite._mongodb.InsertOne(collection, doc)

    // expected
    a.NotNil(insertedID, "the inserted document ID should be returned")
    a.Equal(docID, insertedID, "the inserted document ID should be the same as the given one at creation")
    a.Nil(err, "there should be no error for this insert")

    // then
    _ = e2eSuite._mongodb.DeleteMany(collection, bson.D{})
}

//func (e2eSuite *e2eMongoDBSuite) TestInsertOneWithNoID_OK() {
//  a := assert.New(e2eSuite.T())
//
//  // given
//  doc := &e2eTestDocument{}
//
//  // when
//  insertedID, err := e2eSuite._mongodb.InsertOne(collection, doc)
//
//  // expected
//  a.NotNil(insertedID, "the inserted document ID should be returned")
//  //a.Equal(docID, insertedID, "the inserted document ID should be the same as the given one at creation")
//  a.Nil(err, "there should be no error for this insert")
//
//   // then
//   _ = e2eSuite._mongodb.DeleteMany(collection, bson.D{})
//}

func (e2eSuite *e2eMongoDBSuite) TestInsertManyWithIDs_OK() {
    a := assert.New(e2eSuite.T())

    // given
    docID1 := e2eSuite._mongodb.GenerateNewObjectID()
    docID2 := e2eSuite._mongodb.GenerateNewObjectID()
    doc1 := &e2eTestDocument{ID: docID1}
    doc2 := &e2eTestDocument{ID: docID2}

    // when
    insertedIDs, err := e2eSuite._mongodb.InsertMany(collection, []*e2eTestDocument{doc1, doc2})

    // expected
    a.NotNil(insertedIDs, "the inserted document IDs should be returned")
    a.Equal(2, len(insertedIDs), "the inserted document IDs amount should be of two")
    a.EqualValues([]*primitive.ObjectID{docID1, docID2}, insertedIDs, "the inserted document IDs should be the same as the given ones at creation")
    a.Nil(err, "there should be no error for this insert")

    // then
    _ = e2eSuite._mongodb.DeleteMany(collection, bson.D{})
}

//func (e2eSuite *e2eMongoDBSuite) TestInsertManyWithNoIDs_OK() {
//  a := assert.New(e2eSuite.T())
//
//  // given
//  doc1 := &e2eTestDocument{}
//  doc2 := &e2eTestDocument{}
//
//  // when
//  insertedIDs, err := e2eSuite._mongodb.InsertMany(collection, []*e2eTestDocument{doc1, doc2})
//
//  // expected
//  a.NotNil(insertedIDs, "the inserted document IDs should be returned")
//  a.Equal(2, len(insertedIDs), "the inserted document IDs amount should be of two")
//  a.Nil(err, "there should be no error for this insert")
//
//// then
//_ = e2eSuite._mongodb.DeleteMany(collection, bson.D{})
//}

func (e2eSuite *e2eMongoDBSuite) TearDownSuite() {
    _ = e2eSuite._mongodb.DropDatabase()
}

func TestE2eMongoDBSuite(t *testing.T) {
    suite.Run(t, new(e2eMongoDBSuite))
}
```

***The layer i've developed:***

```
// InsertOne inserts a document in a given collection and returns the inserted ObjectID.
func (m *mongoDB) InsertOne(collectionName string, document interface{}) (*primitive.ObjectID, error) {
    res, err := m.GetDatabase().Collection(collectionName).InsertOne(context.Background(), document)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if oid, ok := res.InsertedID.(primitive.ObjectID); ok {
        return &oid, nil
    }
    return nil, nil
}

// InsertMany inserts documents in a given collection and returns the inserted ObjectIDs.
func (m *mongoDB) InsertMany(collectionName string, documents interface{}) ([]*primitive.ObjectID, error) {

    s := reflect.ValueOf(documents)
    if s.Kind() != reflect.Slice {
        panic("Documents given a non-slice type")
    }

    slice := make([]interface{}, s.Len())
    for i := 0; i < s.Len(); i++ {
        slice[i] = s.Index(i).Interface()
    }

    res, err := m.GetDatabase().Collection(collectionName).InsertMany(context.Background(), slice)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    var insertedIDs []*primitive.ObjectID
    for _, insertedID := range res.InsertedIDs {
        if oid, ok := insertedID.(primitive.ObjectID); ok {
            insertedIDs = append(insertedIDs, &oid)
        }
    }

    return insertedIDs, nil
}
```

**Conclusion**

I don't know if the behavior is logic or not but an id should be generated if my document as no ID :confused:

**Note**

*A topic as been opened here: https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/inserting-a-document-in-go-with-no-id-set-results-into-a-weird-behavior/100359 (don't know if it's a bug or not so I thought I should post there too)*

Thanks!

Max

Comment: If your struct has _id initialized to nil, that is your id. To auto-generate the _id, you have to use a struct that doesn't have _id (not one that is set to nil).

Comment: Hello, wait what.. so using a pointer would be the issue? let me test it now.. sorry it's getting late maybe  missed it but.. let me get back to you

Comment: No it is not the pointer. If you have a struct with `bson:"_id"`, it will use that _id, even if it is nil. For auto-generated _id, you need a struct without _id, i.e. `bson:"_id,omitempty"` should do.

Comment: you're right... thanks a lot :) post an answer i will accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you insert a document containing the `_id` field, mongodb will use that as the document id, even if it is null. To have the `_id` auto-generated, you have to insert the document *without* the `_id` field. This should work:

```
type Doc struct {
  ID         *primitive.ObjectID `json:"_id" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
  ...
```

This will not marshal the `_id` field if it is nil, focing it to be auto-generated.

Comment: You can also add that, it's now (it wasn't at the time) possible to have a  `primitive.NilObjectID` which is an empty ID (that you can validate using mongodb driver function). If you use(d) pointer to make it nullable (or non initialized, as approach, like me), you can now use NilOjectID :) The `omitempty` is also very important, I was missing it, it was actually my issue :)